# How to extract this json into a table?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've a sql column filled with json document, one for row:

```
 [{
    "ID":"TOT",
    "type":"ABS",
    "value":"32.0"
    },

    {
    "ID":"T1",
    "type":"ABS",
    "value":"9.0"
    },

    {
    "ID":"T2",
    "type":"ABS",
    "value":"8.0"
     },

     {
     "ID":"T3",
     "type":"ABS",
     "value":"15.0"
  }]
```

How is it possible to trasform it into tabular form? I tried with redshift `json_extract_path_text` and `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT` function, also I tried with `json_each` and `json_each_text` (on postgres) but didn't get what expected... any suggestions?

desired results should appear like this:

```
T1    T2    T3    TOT
9.0   8.0  15.0   32.0
```

Comment: Just to confim, are you looking to insert your JSON in a table?

Comment: please give an example of exactly what the output should look like. add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you printed 4 rows. In postgresql

```
SELECT this_column->'ID'
FROM   that_table;
```

will return column with JSON strings. Use `->>` if you want text column. More info here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

In case you were using some old Postgresql (before 9.3), this gets harder : )

Comment: This is a redshift question - not postgres.

Comment: @Jon Scott there was tag postgresql when i was writing my answer. Ingus mentiones postgres `json_each` and `json_each_text`.

Comment: This happens a lot with redshift questions! can get confusing.

Comment: @jibet unfortunately it returns me null values....I edited my previous post in order to clarify desired results

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use [COPY from JSON Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html). This will load the JSON directly into a normal table format. You then query it as normal data.

However, I suspect that you will need to slightly modify the format of the file by removing the outer `[...]` square brackets and also the commas between records, eg:

```
{
    "ID": "TOT",
    "type": "ABS",
    "value": "32.0"
}
{
    "ID": "T1",
    "type": "ABS",
    "value": "9.0"
}
```

If, however, your data is already loaded and you cannot re-load the data, you could either extract the data into a new table, or add additional columns to the existing table and use an `UPDATE` command to extract each field into a new column.

Or, very worst case, you can use one of the [JSON Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html) to access the information in a JSON field, but this is very inefficient for large requests (eg in a WHERE clause).